# parseFloat returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get rid of currency sign in order to calculate new price using parseFloat, but it returns nan for some reason.

```
var pricePerUser = "£19.99";
pricePerUser = parseFloat(pricePerUser) * 3;
console.log(pricePerUser); //Returns NaN
```

Comment: because it's not a number?

Comment: Remove the character from it. Then parse it to a float or int.

Comment: For the record, `parseFloat('8px') == 8`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`parseFloat()` will parse each character of a string until it finds a non-numeric value. The `£` is the first character, hence it finds no number to parse. You need to remove that before you call `parseFloat()`:

```
var pricePerUser = "£19.99";
pricePerUser = parseFloat(pricePerUser.replace('£', '')) * 3;
console.log(pricePerUser);
```

> Could you suggest how I can print out numbers like 19.90 instead of 19.9 in this case?

If you require 2DP precision use `toFixed(2)` when displaying the output to the UI:

```
console.log(pricePerUser.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: You are missing closing bracket of the `parseFloat` function. :-)

Comment: You can also remove all non-numeric characters from var. See my below answer

Comment: @dpanshu If you remove all the non-numeric characters, you end up with `1999`, not `19.99`

Comment: Rory, I also tried rounding it to 2 decimal places like so: Math.round((parseFloat(pricePerUser.replace('£', '')) * 3) * 100) / 100 could you suggest how I can print out numbers like 19.90 instead of 19.9 in this case? I'll accept your answer as soon as I can as it solved my question, thank you :)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  edited my answer to resolve the decimal issue

Answer (score 3):

`parseFloat` starts from the beginning of a string and keeps going until it runs out of number symbols.

Since the first character is not a number, it stops immediately and returns `NaN`.

[Use `substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) (or `replace`, etc) to remove the symbol instead.

```js
var pricePerUser = "£19.99";
var currency_value = parseFloat(pricePerUser.substr(1));
console.log(currency_value); //Returns 19.99
```

Comment: @AltayMazlum — It is working — https://www.evernote.com/l/AAO2sXQtzDJFZ5AvFVgTkqW5RPMV_zp1f_kB/image.png

Comment: Oh okay, sorry about that. I admire your work in coding Quentin, didn't mean to act disrespectfully.

Answer (score 3):

Because pricePerUser is not a float number its considered as a string. you have remove the symbol £ using split or replace in javascript and concluded your methods

```
var pricePerUser = "£19.99";
pricePer = parseFloat(pricePerUser.split("£")[1]) * 3;
console.log(pricePer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the string contains alphabets, `parseFloat` returns `NaN`.

You can use `regex` to replace all other characters than numbers and `.`-decimal point. And perform mathematical operations on it.

```js
var pricePerUser = "£19.99".replace(/[^0-9.+-]/g, '') * 3;

document.write(pricePerUser);
```

Comment: ...did you even try your own snippet?

Answer (score 1):

pricePerUser is not a number it has a currency sign, you need to remove any characters from the var before using parseFloat.

```
var pricePerUser = "£19.99";
pricePerUser.replace(/[-+]?(\d*[.])?\d+/,'');
console.log(pricePerUser);
```